# error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Tags: c, pointers, struct

> error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

```
struct test_t {
    int var1[5];
    int var2[10];
    int var3[15];
}

test_t* test;
test->var1[0] = 5;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should write:

```
struct test_t* test;
```

Or use [`typedef`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) if you want to avoid writing `struct` every time you declare a variable of that type:

```
typedef struct test_t {
    int var1[5];
    int var2[10];
    int var3[15];
} test_t;

test_t* test;
```

Side note: In C++ the struct name is placed in the regular namespace, therefore there is no need to write `struct` before declaring a variable of that type.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a structure variable, `struct` keyword should be there like

```
struct test_t* test;
```

If you don't want to use `struct` keyword every time you declare a variable, simply use `typedef`.